# Run spark-shell inside Docker container against remote YARN cluster

Tags: apache-spark, docker, hadoop-yarn

May be someone already had experience to build docker image for spark? 
I want to build docker image with spark inside but configured against remote YARN cluster. 
I have already created image with spark 1.6.2 inside. 
But when I run

```
spark-shell --master yarn --deploy-mode client --driver-memory 32G --executor-memory 32G --executor-cores 8
```

inside docker I get the following exception 
Diagnostics: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/usr/local/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.2-hadoop2.2.0.jar does not exist

Any suggestions? 
Do I need to load spark-assembly i HDFS and set spark.yarn.jar=hdfs://spark-assembly-1.6.2-hadoop2.2.0.jar ?

Here is my Dockerfile 
https://gist.github.com/ponkin/cac0a071e7fe75ca7c390b7388cf4f91

Comment: Unrelated to the error, but do you even have 32GB RAM  and 8 cores allocated to the container?

Comment: Anyways, the error is self explanatory. Why did you download `spark-1.6.2-bin-without-hadoop` if you want to use YARN and HDFS? Keywords: `without-hadoop`

Comment: Have a look at [sequenceiq/spark](https://hub.docker.com/r/sequenceiq/spark/)

Comment: @cricket_007 if you check my Dockerfile, you will see that I have hadoop installed separately. Even If I use spark-withhadoop - the error is the same. The problem that I do not need to run cluster in Docker, I just need to have ability to run spark-shell inside docker (in client mode) against my real YARN cluster

Comment: But Spark doesn't use Hadoop 2.7, uses Hadoop 2.6, which is what the bundled version comes with. And I don't think you can start a Hadoop cluster from the bundled Spark version. It simply includes the tools necessary to be configured and communicate with Hadoop cluster

Comment: @cricket_007 Well I do not need to start cluster inside docker. I have remote cluster. I just want to run spark-shell in client mode inside docker container against my real remote cluster

Comment: I understood that. If you compare the contents of the `/usr/local/spark/lib/` directory for the Spark with Hadoop vs Spark without Hadoop, you may find the JAR that you are missing